# MATLAB: ranova and fitrm error message: "Input to EIG must not contain NaN or Inf."

Tags: matlab, statistics, nan, anova

I have data from 5 trials. Each trial yields two measurements: m1 and m2.

I would like to know if m1 and m2 are significantly different across trials, or if all five trials are roughly the same.
I am using ranova to do this:

```
%data
m1=[5.75636538694097e-05;1.10717342719571e-07;1.13871552566709e-07;1.02149099965413e-07;1.00010316577243e-07];
m2=[2.95033146169489e-05;3.11966223064457e-05;4.11372088008447e-05;3.47615239811505e-05;1.79196757006156e-05];
trial = {'jun10';'jun23';'jun24';'jul01';'jul02'};  %column vector of trial names

% create data table
t = table(trial,m1,m2,'VariableNames',{'trial','m1','m2'});   
Meas = dataset([1 2]','VarNames',{'Measurements'});     

%fit a repeated measures model
rm = fitrm(t,'m1-m2~trial','WithinDesign',Meas); 

%perform repeated measure analysis of variance
ranovatbl = ranova(rm);
```

When I run this code, I get the following error messages:

```
>Error using eig
>Input to EIG must not contain NaN or Inf.
> 
> Error in RepeatedMeasuresModel>mauchlyTest (line 1921) lam =
> eig(C'*S*C);
> 
> Error in RepeatedMeasuresModel.fit (line 1369)
>             [this.Mauchly,this.Epsilon] = mauchlyTest(this.Cov,size(Xmat,1),rank(Xmat));
> 
> Error in fitrm (line 67) s =
> RepeatedMeasuresModel.fit(ds,model,varargin{:});
```

I don't have any NaN or Inf values in my data. What is the problem that fitrm is encountering?

Comment: Well, MATLAB gives you the backtrace. It seems that `C'SC` is given to the `eig` function as an input. So this will contain `NaN` or `Inf`. Set a breakpoint at the call and check the values there.

Comment: I did see that, but my understanding of MATLAB is not good enough to understand _why_ there are NaN or Inf values coming up in C or S, and what to do about it. Also fixed the formatting so the error message is easier to read.